# store custom exception in Event Log object

Tags: apex, rest-api, rest, apexrest, rest-service

I am trying to create a EventLog (Custom object) record when ever a exception is caught. It works fine only when the system exception occurs (Like any DML operation. In my case If I call Update instead of Insert in try block). How can I catch the custom exception and store it as a record in Eventlog. Below is the code that I am using. Here I am checking if all the fields received from External system are correct and not Null. And if the value of the fields like Ids have 18 characters. If so, then I am showing a custom error as response.

I want to catch all the errors like, If the AccountId has less than 18 characters, catch that as exception with the field name and create a record in EventLog object. Any help would be really appreciated.

```
    @RestResource(urlMapping='/cases/V1/caseservice/')
global with sharing class RESTWebservice 
{ 

@HttpPost   
  global static String createNewCase() {
     RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
     RestResponse res = RestContext.response;
     createNewCase response= new createNewCase();
      Boolean MissingData=False;
      Boolean Dataexception=False;

      // Convert the request body to string.
      string request = req.requestbody.tostring();

      // Deserialize the JSON request that is received using the inner class.
      IncomingRequest R = (IncomingRequest)JSON.deserialize(request, IncomingRequest.Class);

       if(R.sfclientid==null || R.sfaccountid==null)
       {       
           MissingData=True;
       }
        if(R.sfclientid.length()<18 || R.sfaccountid.length()<18)
       {
          Dataexception=True;
       }

      Case c = new Case();      

      Map<string, DFM_Js__c> cs = DFM_Js__c.getAll();  
      List<String> Formnames = new List<String>();
      Formnames.addAll(cs.keySet());
      for(string dm:Formnames)
      {
        DFM_Js__c fn=cs.get(dm);
          system.debug('** MissingData before assigning values to case fields' + MissingData);
          system.debug('**Dataexception before assigning values to case fields ' + Dataexception);

        if(Dataexception==False || MissingData==False)
         {
          // COmpare the documenttype field value received with Form Name field in custom settings.
          if(R.documenttype==fn.FormName__c)
          {
              c.Status=fn.Case_Status__c;   
              c.Subject = R.Subject;
              c.AccountId__c=R.sfaccountid;     
          }          
       }
      }
      try
      {
          if(MissingData && Dataexception)
          {
               res.statusCode=400;
               response.message='Required Fields are missings and Wrong Ids Received'; 

          } 
         else if(MissingData)
          {
              res.statusCode=400;                         
              response.message='Missing Data - Required Fields are missings';
          }
         else  if(Dataexception)
          {
              res.statusCode=400;
              response.message='Data Exception - Received wrong Ids';
          }        
          else 
          {             
              Insert c;
              res.statusCode=201;
              response.status = 'Success';
              response.message = 'Case created successfully with case ID'+' '+ c.Id;          
         }
      }

      catch(Exception ex) 
      {

        // create a record in Event Log object if there is any error occuring when creation of case.
        CreateErrorMesage(c,'Case','RESTWebservice','RESTWebservice.createNewCase()',ex);            
      }
      return response.message;
  }


    // Create a record in Error Log object if there is any error occured when creating of case record.
    public static void CreateErrorMesage(SObject acc, String ObjName, string EventType, string ProcessName, Exception ex){
     try{ 
            string errormessage;
            Event_Log__c eventlog = new Event_Log__c();
            eventlog.ObjectName__c= ObjName;
            eventlog.ObjectId__c = acc.Id;
            eventlog.EventType__c = EventType;
            eventlog.ProcessName__c=ProcessName; 
            errormessage =  ex.getTypeName() + ': '  + ex.getCause() +' At Line'+ ex.getLineNumber() + 'Stack Trace:-'+ex.getStackTraceString();
            if(errormessage.length() < 32000) eventlog.StackTrace__c = errormessage;
            else eventlog.StackTrace__c = errormessage.SubString(0,32000);
            eventlog.ErrorMessage__c =  ex.getMessage();
            eventlog.UserInfo__c = Userinfo.getUserId()+ '|' +Userinfo.getFirstName();
            insert eventlog;
      } catch(Exception e){}  
  }  


  public class incomingrequest{
      public string sfclientid;
      public string sfaccountid;    
      incomingrequest(){}       
  }

    global class createNewCase {      
        public String status;
        public String message;

        public createNewCase(){

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`try/catch` works only when the system throws an exception or you throw a custom exception.  It does not work in if/else structures unless something causes an exception, e.g. you try to assign a string value to an integer variable.

If you want to use custom exceptions, first you need to create [Custom Exceptions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_exception_custom.htm).  You could create an exception class with various categories like this:

```
public virtual class MyExceptions {
  public class RequiredException extends Exception {}
  public class ValidationException extends Exception {}
}
```

Then you need to wrap your request parsing process in a try/catch and throw exceptions as needed within the if statements:

```
try {
    IncomingRequest R = (IncomingRequest)JSON.deserialize(request, IncomingRequest.Class);
    if(R.sfclientid==null || R.sfaccountid==null) {       
     throw new MyExceptions.RequiredException('A required field is missing');
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    // do your logging here.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response David. This is how I planned and I am doing when I did not receive any response for my question.. But you are right.  We need to use custom exception.